How do I wrap a struct using ECL's SFFI?
Here is a C struct:
struct list {
  int *data; 
  int numItems; 
  int size; 
};

I'm using ECL (Embeddable Common Lisp) to make one of these structs. I'm using ECL's inline c features, which allows me to mix Lisp and C code.
I want to make a function that returns a pointer to one of these structs. It should be easy...
(defun make-dynamic-array (size)
  (ffi:c-inline (size) (:int) ???
                "
struct list *ptr;
ptr->data = malloc(sizeof(*ptr->data) * #0);
ptr->size = #0;
@(return)=<cast?>ptr;"))

The problem is that I don't know what to put at ??? and <cast?>.
What's the right way to wrap a struct using ECL's extensions? Should I give up and use CFFI?
I've tried many iterations, like (:struct ...) and pointers to the name of the struct. The only way to make anything compile is to return a void pointer. This seems like a poor choice.

If you want ECL to know about the struct you probably need to tell it, for instance with def-struct.

Yes, I did that, but the information still didn't come through.
